# Angular Material Date Picker Size Error

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-material

I've been trying to use the Material Datepicker, but when I come to large screens the picker format blows up (see image), even though I define it an md-content environment it uses and takes up the whole screen. How do I limit the size of the picker container as it works correctly when the screen is set to smaller sizes. It makes sense to set it so it never gets larger than a given number of pixels but I can't work out/find the CSS tags to do this.

[image]

My HTML of the picker is copied from the demo:

```
 <md-content layout-padding>
    <div layout-gt-xs="row">
      <div flex-gt-xs>
        <h4>Standard date-picker</h4>
        <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
      </div>
    </div>
    </md-content>
```

Trying this CSS yields no results

```
.md-datepicker-input-container {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have run into to this issue.

Ensure you dont have in one of your css files

```
table {
    width:100%;
}
```

Remove this was the solution for me

Answer (score 0):

The date picker seems to be running fine. [Here](http://codepen.io/divyanshu013/pen/XjPNQO) is my pen. Check the pen and see if you've included everything in your full code.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" class="datepickerdemoBasicUsage" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-content layout-padding="">

    <div layout-gt-xs="row">
      <div flex-gt-xs="">
        <h4>Standard date-picker</h4>
        <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
      </div>
    </div>

  </md-content>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache']).controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myDate = new Date();
});
```

**CSS**

```
.datepickerdemoBasicUsage {
  /** Demo styles for mdCalendar. */ }
  .datepickerdemoBasicUsage md-content {
    padding-bottom: 200px; }
  .datepickerdemoBasicUsage .validation-messages {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #dd2c00;
    margin-left: 15px; }
```